# Antd file upload appending file after returning false from beforeUpload

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd file upload and I want to prevent user from uploading more than 2mb file.
my `beforeUpload` is:

```
 beforeUpload(file: File) {
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    notification["error"]({
      message: `File must smaller than 2MB!`,
    });
  }
  return isLt2M;
}
```

Notification is working but the file is still uploaded.

Comment: You should handle any kind of validation in backend,

Comment: we are trying to handle it in frontend too

Comment: What do you mean by *file is still uploaded.*? Was the file uploaded to the remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to return `Upload.LIST_IGNORE` when you want to prevent file from uploading, like this:

```
function beforeUpload(file) {
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    notification["error"]({
      message: `File must smaller than 2MB!`,
    });
  }
  return isLt2M || Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
}
```